# Unix shell / ssh - How to remove folder "backups\r\r"

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, directory, rm

I accidentally created a directory named: `backups\r\r`. 
Any attempt at deleting it failed!

How can this directory be deleted?

Comment: What is you shell? Use `echo $0`

Comment: `bash` it is! If it helps you.

Comment: Please use ll and paste exact name of directory created..

Comment: Type `rmdir backups` and then hit tab.  It will autocomplete with the properly escaped version of the directory, and then you can hit return.

Comment: @PaulTomblin This is also an option I didn't think off thank you!

Comment: @MayankJain This was the exact name of the directory. It got displayed like that when I used the dir command!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting): `rmdir $'backups\r\r'`

or delete interactively with [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching): `rmdir -i backups??`

Answer (score 2):

You must escape the backslashes:

```
rmdir backups\\r\\r/
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. This is the error I get: `rmdir: failed to remove `backups\\r\\r/': No such file or directory` (I'm in the correct directory to delete it)

Comment: If you don't have any other directories named backups you can try: `rmdir backups*`. This will remove all directories that begin with backup in the working directory.

Comment: Note that this solution fails because the directory name ends with a pair of ASCII carriage returns, not the 4-character string `\r\r`.